# Taking a derivative of a derivative of a surface.

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm currently studying by myself [Differential Geometry with Kreyszig's book](https://books.google.com.mx/books/about/Differential_Geometry.html?id=Vw3CAgAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y#:%7E:text=Differential%20Geometry-,Erwin%20Kreyszig,in%20three%2Ddimensional%20Euclidean%20space.).

I'm starting chapter 4. The 1st section is about the 2nd fundamental form:

[image]

As usual, I like to thoroughly go about the reasoning on how we get there. Kreyszig doesn't talk much about it as with other sections, yet I took the challenge to expand the solution by myself. Given the following notation (used in the book):
[image]

I want to arrive to the following:

[image]

Which is used in the process. I already have most of it:

[image]

[image]

How do I work out those last two derivatives? I'm thinking a sort of chain rule may be present but I'm not that sure at all. Expanding what I have to arrive at, those 2 terms end up being 4 which are resumed in summation notation.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Please write an *informative* title... one that relates to the specific content of your question.

Comment: Couldn't you have contradicted the indices on $x_i $ and $ \dot{u}^i$

Comment: I'm not sure you correctly understand what it is that you are calculating. The surface does not change as the arclength changes. It's all about the curve that is a subset of the surface. You're comparing its acceleration with an arbitrary parametrization to its acceleration with an arclength parametrization.

Comment: @Fernado Garcia Cortez I am glad my answer helped you, but I would echo what David G. Stork said. If you edit the question, then it will be useful to more people :)

Comment: @Buraian I agree, yet I can't come up with a better title. I was also aware that my understanding of what the derivative actually meant was a bit of. Do you have something in mind?

Comment: I am working through a similar book on this, I'll perhaps say more specific comments when I reach the chapters dealing with surfaces. However, I think if you can put exactly what wasn't clear about the derivatives on surface concept into a question, then I can try and attempt the question when I know a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think, the problematic terms here are:

$$ \dot{u}^i \frac{d}{ds}x_i \tag{1}$$

Now by the chain rule we can write the derivative with $s$ as,

$$ \frac{d}{ds} = \frac{du^j}{ds} \frac{d}{du^j}$$

Hence,

$$ \frac{d}{ds} x_i = \frac{du^j}{ds} \frac{d}{du^j} x_i \tag{2}$$

And, we can also use the fact that:

$$ \frac{d}{du^j} x_i =x_{ij} \tag{3}$$

Putting everything together:

$$ \dot{u}^i \frac{du^j}{ds} x_{ij}$$

Now to finish, I guess that $ \frac{du^j}{ds} = \dot{u}^j$?